# Calculation dimensionless time function thermal coductivity?

Tags: math, calculation, temperature, heat, bessel-functions

Currently I am trying to do some experiments to try to determine thermal conductivity of my fluid which is ethanol.

To do so, I need to use the principle of TPS method which correspond to the kind of sensor I have.

I would like to plot on python ∆D(τ) function of τ and also, ∆T function of D(τ)

Basically, I have these formula which correspond to ∆D(τ).

[formula ∆D(τ)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M7Fc.png)

[other variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDy8t.png)
[other variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5y92.png)

where Io is a modified Bessel function.

The paper that I am reading contains the following information that might help.

"From Eq X (D thau), we can see that the average temperature
increase in the hot disk sensor is proportional to a function
D(τ), which is a rather complicated function of a dimen-
sionless parameter τ = √κt/a, but, numerically, it can be
accurately evaluated to five or six significant figures.
When using the hot disk technique to determine thermal
transport properties, a constant electric current is supplied
to the sensor at time t = 0, then the temperature change of
the sensor is recorded as a function of time. The average
temperature increase across the hot disk sensor area can be
measured by monitoring the total resistance of the hot disk
sensor:
R = R0[1 + α  ̄deltaT (t)], (28)
where R is the total electrical resistance at time t, R0 is the
initial resistance at t = 0, α is the temperature coefficient of
resistivity, which is well known for nickel. Eq. (28) allows us
to accurately determine ∆T as a function of time.
If one knows the relationship between t and τ, one can
plot   ̄∆T as a function of D(τ), and a straight line should
be obtained. The slope of that line is P0/(π3/2aK), from
which thermal conductivity K can be calculated. However,
the proper value of τ is generally unknown, since τ = √κt/a
and the thermal diffusivity κ is unknown. To calculate the
thermal conductivity correctly, one normally makes a series
of computational plots of ∆T versus D(τ) for a range of κ
values. The correct value of κ will yield a straight line for the
∆T versus D(τ) plot. This optimization process can be done
by the software until an optimized value of κ is found. In
practice, we can measure the density and the specific heat of
the material separately, so that between K and κ, there is only
one independent parameter. Therefore, both thermal conduc-
tivity and thermal diffusivity of the sample can be obtained
from above procedure based on the transient measurement
using a hot disk sensor"

So if I understood I need to plot  ∆T versus D(τ) from which for a certain value of characteristic time which would give me a straight line. However when I am trying to do so I will always obtain a  straight line. the part that I'm not sure if the value of the modified bessel function. Please find attached my script .

```py
    from  numpy import *
    import scipy.special
    from scipy.integrate import quad
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *
    def integer1(sigma):
        return 1/(sigma**2)
     
    tini = 0.015
    tfin = 15
    time = linspace(tini,tfin,num=1000)
    n=7 # number of concentric circles of sensor 
    L = 1
    L0 = np.i0(l*k)/(2*thau**2*n**2)
    P0 = 0.1 #power
    k = 1 #thermal diffusivity
    a = 0.000958 # radius of biggest ring 
    λ = 0.169 #thermal conductivity of ethanol (im not sure if this is ok)
    x=linspace(0.00000001,0.3,1000)
    for K in range (0,len(x)):
        # print (x[K])
        
        theta = a**2/x[K]
        Tlist = []
        Dlist = []
        
        for t in time:
        
            thau = sqrt(t/theta)
            
            som = 0
            for l in range(L,n):
                for k in range(1,n):
                    
                    som += l*k*exp((-l**2+-k**2)/(4*thau**2*n**2))*L0
            
            I = quad(integer1, 0, thau)
            
            D = ((n*(n+1))**-2)*I[0]*som
            
            T = (P0/(pi**(3/2)*a*λ))*D
            
            Tlist.append(T)
            Dlist.append(D)
            
        figure(1)
        plot(Dlist,Tlist)
    show()
```

I am trying to the calculation from time 0,015 seconds until 15 seconds with 1000 points in total..0,015, 0,030, 0,045 and so on...
and I for my K I am going from values  of 0.00000001 until 0.3 with 1000 points in total

The paper that I am looking at is called:
"Rapid thermal conductivity measurement with
a hot disk sensor. Part 1. Theoretical considerations"

I hope you could help with this one.

Thank you

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: I strongly recommend never writing `from ... import *` in python. Especially doing it with two different libraries, such as `from numpy import *; from matplotlib.pyplot import *` is especially confusing because if a function from `numpy` has the same name as a function from `matplotlib.pyplot`, you don't know which one you're using. Instead I recommend `import numpy as np; import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: Interesting question, however, it's off topic here since it's not a specific programming question. Try physics.stackexchange.com instead. You have made a good start, but the whole problem is complex enough that readers won't be able to make sense of what's going on. Try breaking down the problem into pieces and work on each piece separately. That will help you make progress, and also ask more focused questions.